# Trying to make a new object from three exsisting objects using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three objects each are serialized from Django-rest framework.
Each object is a array of a user in a profile. Each profile needs one org_id and email to be valid. "activeUsers" and "inactiveUsers" will never have a
duplicates, each element shares the same org_id, and user_id and email will always be different. "nonProfileUsers" are all the other profiles that exlude
"activeUsers" and "inactiveUsers" org_id, note user_id and email can and will show up more then once.

```
 activeUsers = [
    { "org_id": 1, "user_id": 9, "firstName": "Joj", "lastName": "Blonde", "email": "bop@test.ca", },
    {"org_id": 1, "user_id": 1, "firstName": "Tyler", "lastName": "Whitfield", "email": "tyler@atg.net", },
  ]

inactiveUsers = [
  {  "org_id": 1, "user_id": 3, "firstName": "James", "lastName": "Bond", "email": "test@test.ca", },
  {"org_id": 1, "user_id": 2, "firstName": "Chen", "lastName": "rain", "email": "posihdun@gmail.com", }
]

//user that are in different profiles
nonProfileUsers = [
  { "org_id": 2, "user_id": 2, "firstName": "Chen", "lastName": "rain", "email": "posihdun@gmail.com", },
  {  "org_id": 3, "user_id": 6, "firstName": "weak", "lastName": "jdf", "email": "not@not.ca", },
  {  "org_id": 3, "user_id": 2, "firstName": "Chen", "lastName": "rain", "email": "posihdun@gmail.com", },
  {  "org_id": 4, "user_id": 2, "firstName": "Chen", "lastName": "rain", "email": "posihdun@gmail.com", },
  {  "org_id": 3, "user_id": 3, "firstName": "James", "lastName": "Bond", "email": "test@test.ca", },
  {  "org_id": 2, "user_id": 5, "firstName": "test", "lastName": "test", "email": "tester@tester.ca", },
  { "org_id": 2, "user_id": 3, "firstName": "James", "lastName": "Bond", "email": "test@test.ca", },
]
```

I am using java-script and I need to do a few things.
scale down "nonProfileUsers" to remove duplicated user_id and email combination, but keep at least one org_id(which one is kept does not matter)

```
scaledNonProfileUsers = [
          { "org_id": 2, "user_id": 2, "firstName": "Chen", "lastName": "rain", "email": "posihdun@gmail.com", },
          {  "org_id": 3, "user_id": 6, "firstName": "weak", "lastName": "jdf", "email": "not@not.ca", },
          {  "org_id": 2, "user_id": 5, "firstName": "test", "lastName": "test", "email": "tester@tester.ca", },
          { "org_id": 2, "user_id": 3, "firstName": "James", "lastName": "Bond", "email": "test@test.ca", },
        ]
```

combined "activeUsers" and "inactiveUsers"
-I was able to complete step 2

```
 combinedUsers= [
        { "org_id": 1, "user_id": 9, "firstName": "Joj", "lastName": "Blonde", "email": "bop@test.ca", },
        {"org_id": 1, "user_id": 1, "firstName": "Tyler", "lastName": "Whitfield", "email": "tyler@atg.net", },
        {  "org_id": 1, "user_id": 3, "firstName": "James", "lastName": "Bond", "email": "test@test.ca", },
       {"org_id": 1, "user_id": 2, "firstName": "Chen", "lastName": "rain", "email": "posihdun@gmail.com", }
      ]
```

Make a new object from comparing "scaledNonProfileUsers" vs "combinedUsers".  The emails that are in "scaledNonProfileUsers" and not in "combinedUsers"
will make the final object.

```
finalObj= [
            {  "org_id": 3, "user_id": 6, "firstName": "weak", "lastName": "jdf", "email": "not@not.ca", },
            {  "org_id": 2, "user_id": 5, "firstName": "test", "lastName": "test", "email": "tester@tester.ca", },
          ]
```

I am really struggling with steps 1 and 3.

If I isolate just the email I can make a array like so

```
[
    0:"non@not.ca",
    1:"tester@tester.ca"
  ]
```

But I need to include at least one org_id and email.

This code has been my approach thus far.

```
const temp_active = [...inactiveUsers, ...activeUsers,]// master list of both active/inactive

  const scaledNonProfileUsers= []//isolate email and make a list of emails
  for (var i = 0; i < nonProfileUsers?.length; i++) {
    scaledNonProfileUsers.push(nonProfileUsers[i]?.email)
  }

  const combinedUsers= []//isolate email and make a list of emails
  for (var i = 0; i < temp_active?.length; i++) {
   combinedUsers.push(temp_active[i]?.email)
  }

  let combinedUsers_filter = combinedUsers.filter((c, index) => {//filter duplicated emails
    return combinedUsers.indexOf(c) === index;
  });
  let scaledNonProfileUsers_filter = scaledNonProfileUsers.filter((c, index) => {//filter duplicate emails
    return scaledNonProfileUsers.indexOf(c) === index;
  });

  var finalObj = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < scaledNonProfileUsers_filter?.length; i++) {
    if (!eleContainsInArray(combinedUsers_filter, scaledNonProfileUsers_filter[i])) {
      finalObj.push(scaledNonProfileUsers_filter[i])
    }
  }
  function eleContainsInArray(arr, element) {
    if (arr != null && arr.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == element)
          return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  console.log(finalObj)
```

Anyone help would be much appreciated.

Comment: _scale down "nonProfileUsers" to remove duplicated user_id and email combination_ --> Please try: `const scaledNonProfileUsers = nonProfileUsers.filter(({ user_id, email }, idx) => idx === nonProfileUsers.findIndex(ob => ob.user_id === user_id && ob.email === email))` & share your feedback. This should retain the first among duplicates and filter-out the rest.

Comment: _emails that are in "scaledNonProfileUsers" and not in "combinedUsers" will make the final object_ ---> Please try: `const finalObj = scaledNonProfileUsers.filter(({ email }) => !combinedUsers.map(({ email }) => email).includes(email));` and share your feedback. If either or both work, or if you have any questions/clarifications, let me know - and we can post an answer to take this further.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I was able to make it work, but I did have to convert nonProfileUsers to a array:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `reduce()` to loop inside array and `include()` to filter element match or not match:

```js
var activeUsers = [
    { "org_id": 1, "user_id": 9, "firstName": "Joj", "lastName": "Blonde", "email": "bop@test.ca", },
    {"org_id": 1, "user_id": 1, "firstName": "Tyler", "lastName": "Whitfield", "email": "tyler@atg.net", },
  ]

var inactiveUsers = [
  {  "org_id": 1, "user_id": 3, "firstName": "James", "lastName": "Bond", "email": "test@test.ca", },
  {"org_id": 1, "user_id": 2, "firstName": "Chen", "lastName": "rain", "email": "posihdun@gmail.com", }
]

//user that are in different profiles
var nonProfileUsers = [
  { "org_id": 2, "user_id": 2, "firstName": "Chen", "lastName": "rain", "email": "posihdun@gmail.com", },
  {  "org_id": 3, "user_id": 6, "firstName": "weak", "lastName": "jdf", "email": "not@not.ca", },
  {  "org_id": 3, "user_id": 2, "firstName": "Chen", "lastName": "rain", "email": "posihdun@gmail.com", },
  {  "org_id": 4, "user_id": 2, "firstName": "Chen", "lastName": "rain", "email": "posihdun@gmail.com", },
  {  "org_id": 3, "user_id": 3, "firstName": "James", "lastName": "Bond", "email": "test@test.ca", },
  {  "org_id": 2, "user_id": 5, "firstName": "test", "lastName": "test", "email": "tester@tester.ca", },
  { "org_id": 2, "user_id": 3, "firstName": "James", "lastName": "Bond", "email": "test@test.ca", },
]

const scaledNonProfileUsers = nonProfileUsers.reduce((prev, curr) => (prev.map(el => el.user_id).includes(curr.user_id) || prev.map(el => el.email).includes(curr.email)) ? [...prev] : [...prev, curr], [])
const combinedUsers = [...inactiveUsers, ...activeUsers]
const finalObj =  scaledNonProfileUsers.reduce((prev, curr) => (combinedUsers.map(el => el.email).includes(curr.email)) ? [...prev] : [...prev, curr], [])
console.log(finalObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const activeUsers = [
    {
        org_id: 1,
        user_id: 9,
        firstName: 'Joj',
        lastName: 'Blonde',
        email: 'bop@test.ca',
    },
    {
        org_id: 1,
        user_id: 1,
        firstName: 'Tyler',
        lastName: 'Whitfield',
        email: 'tyler@atg.net',
    },
]

const inactiveUsers = [
    {
        org_id: 1,
        user_id: 3,
        firstName: 'James',
        lastName: 'Bond',
        email: 'test@test.ca',
    },
    {
        org_id: 1,
        user_id: 2,
        firstName: 'Chen',
        lastName: 'rain',
        email: 'posihdun@gmail.com',
    },
]

const nonProfileUsers = [
    {
        org_id: 2,
        user_id: 2,
        firstName: 'Chen',
        lastName: 'rain',
        email: 'posihdun@gmail.com',
    },
    {
        org_id: 3,
        user_id: 6,
        firstName: 'weak',
        lastName: 'jdf',
        email: 'not@not.ca',
    },
    {
        org_id: 3,
        user_id: 2,
        firstName: 'Chen',
        lastName: 'rain',
        email: 'posihdun@gmail.com',
    },
    {
        org_id: 4,
        user_id: 2,
        firstName: 'Chen',
        lastName: 'rain',
        email: 'posihdun@gmail.com',
    },
    {
        org_id: 3,
        user_id: 3,
        firstName: 'James',
        lastName: 'Bond',
        email: 'test@test.ca',
    },
    {
        org_id: 2,
        user_id: 5,
        firstName: 'test',
        lastName: 'test',
        email: 'tester@tester.ca',
    },
    {
        org_id: 2,
        user_id: 3,
        firstName: 'James',
        lastName: 'Bond',
        email: 'test@test.ca',
    },
]

const filteredNonProfileUsers = nonProfileUsers.reduce((prev, current) => {
    if (
        prev.find(
            user =>
                user.user_id === current.user_id || user.email === current.email
        )
    )
        return prev

    return [...prev, current]
}, [])

const activeUsersAndInactiveUsers = [...activeUsers, ...inactiveUsers]

const result = filteredNonProfileUsers.reduce((prev, current) => {
    if (
        activeUsersAndInactiveUsers.find(
            user =>
                user.user_id === current.user_id || user.email === current.email
        )
    )
        return prev

    return [...prev, current]
}, [])

console.log(result)
```